# Android NDK app building failure "arguments list too long" with Cygwin

Tags: android, command-line-arguments, irrlicht

I'm trying to build irrlicht android port on windows xp sp3 with android NDK r5 on cygwin, but  fail with error "arguments list too long".

I googled, and got some solution from [this post](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=43449) which tries to add some extra makefile script to use separate .linkargs file for linker. I followed the instruction but still failed(I replied the post with the error information there).

So, what would be the valid way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out SG57's answer at 
http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=43449#p260385

It solves the problem by using a temporary file and indirecting args through it.